# HackerRank says ~ no response on stdout ~ C

Tags: c

I'm having this issue while trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/icecream-parlor?h_r=internal-search) question on HackerRank.
On repl.it my code goes well, but on their console i have this problem.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int t; //qtd de viagens
  int m; //dinheiro para os sorvetes
  int n; //qtd de sabores de sorvetes
  int c[n+1]; //preço de cada sorvete
  int r[t];
  int s[t];

  scanf("%d", &t);
  for(int j = 0; j < t; j++){
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
      for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &c[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        for(int k =i+1; k <= n; k++){
          if (c[i]+c[k] == m){
            r[j] = i;
            s[j] = k;
          }
        }
      }
  }  
  for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
    printf("%d %d\n", *&r[i], *&s[i]);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
 2
 4
 5
 1 4 5 3 2
 4
 4
 2 2 4 3
```

Output on repl.it:

```
1 4
1 2
```

Output on HackerRank:

```
~ no response on stdout ~
```

It also gives me a Segmentation Fault message.

Comment: `int n; int c[n+1];` What value is `n` at that point do you think? Same for `t`.

Comment: Comment your code in english, please. Especially if it's to be reviewed in a multilanguage community.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding something, but couldn't `printf("%d %d\n", r[i], s[i]);` be used instead of `printf("%d %d\n", *&r[i], *&s[i]);`?

Comment: @BobJarvis it seems to work well too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int t, m, n; 
  //Declaration of dynamic arrays "r", "s" and "c"
  int *c, *r, *s;

  scanf("%d", &t);
  //Allocation of memory for  the int arrays "r" and "s"
  r = malloc(t * sizeof(int));
  s = malloc(t * sizeof(int));
  for(int j=0; j < t; j++){
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
   //Allocation of memory for the int array "c"
    c = malloc(n+1 * sizeof(int));
      for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &c[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        for(int k = i+1; k <= n; k++){
          if ((c[i] + c[k]) == m){
            r[j] = i;
            s[j] = k;
          }
        }
      }
   free(c);
  }  
  for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
    printf("%d %d\n", *&r[i], *&s[i]);
  }
  free(r);
  free(s);

  return 0;
}
```

I use valgrind to detect memory leaks:

```
==53541== HEAP SUMMARY:
==53541==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==53541==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 2,081 bytes allocated
==53541== 
==53541== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: And how about using `free()` as well?

Comment: Please provide explanation (and possible reasoning) about what kind of modification you have made in the original code to write the code you have provided.

Comment: @Muntasir I declared a dynamic arrays and I allocated for it the memory address.I edited my answer you can check it now.

Comment: Note that it is [redundant and potentially dangerous to cast the result of malloc and friends in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/253056).

Comment: Also your code has a huge memory leak - look at where you are allocating and freeing `c`.

Comment: @PaulR I edited the answer. Can you check with me if it still any memory leaks?

Comment: @HmidiSlim: yes, that looks better - also thanks for removing the redundant casts. Down-vote removed.

Comment: Thanks, i'm learning C and I don't know a lot of functions yet. I'm also having some difficulties with memory allocation.

Comment: @GabrielMancini don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here:

1. You are using VLA and its not supported by all compilers.
   I'm talking about that:
   `int c[n+1]` for example. Chage that to dynamic allocation
2. Initiallize variables with values before you use them (like you did with `n` and `t`).

Comment: I doubt that HackerRank uses a C compiler which does not support C99 (and therefore VLAs).

Comment: I tried on their compiler and  it and gave me wierd results.